# Invite friends to try facebook app does not work

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have the following js code but it does not work, i've tryed too much but no success:
•i already have a non expire full access token
•i have all permisions

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<title>Invite</title>
</head>
<body>
<A href="#" onMouseOver="return changeImage()" ><img
name="jsbutton" src="http://cdn.property118.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06              /Invite-      friends-to-read-Property118-.jpeg" width="110" height="28" border="0" 
alt="javascript button"></A> 
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ appId: xxxxxxxx, 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
        version    : 'v2.1'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
function renderMFS() {
// First get the list of friends for this user with the Graph API
FB.api('/me/invitable_friends?limit=3000&access_token="I already have a non expire full user access token", 
function(response) {
var container = document.getElementById('mfs');
var mfsForm = document.createElement('form');
mfsForm.id = 'mfsForm';

// Iterate through the array of friends object and create a checkbox for each one.
for(var i = 0; i < Math.min(response.data.length, 10); i++) {
 var friendItem = document.createElement('div');
 friendItem.id = 'friend_' + response.data[i].id;
 friendItem.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="friends" value="'
   + response.data[i].id
   + '" />' + response.data[i].name;
   mfsForm.appendChild(friendItem);
 }
 container.appendChild(mfsForm);

 // Create a button to send the Request(s)
 var sendButton = document.createElement('input');
 sendButton.type = 'button';
 sendButton.value = 'Send Request';
 sendButton.onclick = sendRequest;
 mfsForm.appendChild(sendButton);
 });
 }
 }
 });


</SCRIPT>
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

i want my code show something like this [Example](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t39.2178-6/851585_163249247197268_803234349_n.png) but when I click the botton nothing happens. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no non expiring User Access Token, an Extended User Token is valid for 60 days. But in any case, you don´t need to worry about Access Tokens while using the JavaScript SDK, because it takes care of the User Token for you.

That being said, there are a LOT of problems in that code:

- The biggest problem is that you don´t have any authorization routine. Use [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) to authorize users. And again, don´t worry about Access Tokens.
- You are trying to use the synchronous AND the asynchronous way to include the JavaScript SDK. Always use the asynchronous way and forget about the synchronous way.
- You are using FB.getLoginStatus and FB.api before initializing the JS SDK with FB.init. The whole block of code with FB.getLoginStatus should be either right after FB.init or in a function that is called on user interaction (mouse click).
- That link does not do anything. There is no changeImage function anywhere in your code.
- There is also no sendRequest function anywhere, and you are trying to call that function with that input button.

Just open your browser console and you may see some errors pointing some of those things out.

Btw, here´s an article about how to use the JS SDK in a proper way: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: thanks, i bug some things and renew my code but it is still not working here is the new [code](http://herbalista.hol.es/invite.html). sorry i am new with FB JS SDK, i've being working with graph api on google apps script and it its ok...i am working with this [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/multi-friend-selector/v2.2)

Comment: "TypeError: response.data is undefined" - you need to debug "response" alone.